# Create a new column based on multiple conditions of one string column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(city = structure(c(1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 9L, 
8L, 3L), .Label = c("bj", "cq", "cs", "nj", "sh", "tj", "wh", 
"xa", "xm"), class = "factor"), area = c(1580.86, 1927.95, 532.24, 
613.09, 1459.86, 1024.58, 684.63, NA, 708.35), price = c(9.51, 
94.42, 10.77, 8.58, 38.07, 94.14, 30.43, 45.73, 41.39)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Now I want to create a new columns `level` based on the following conditions:

for `bj` and `sh`, the values of `level` are `a`;
for `cq` and `tj`, the values of `level` are `b`; for the others cities, the values are `c`.

How could I do that in R? Thanks.

Comment: In your real dataset, do you only have a small number of levels as in this example? If you have a lot more, it's probably easier to create another table and merge. For example, something like `ind <- data.frame(city = c("bj", "sh", "tj", "cq", "nj", "wh", "xm", "xa", "cs"), level = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d")); merge(df, ind)`.

Comment: In this case, only small number of levels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(level = ifelse(city %in% c("bj", "sh"), "a", 
                             ifelse(city %in% c("cq", "tj"), "b", "c")))


  city    area price level
1   bj 1580.86  9.51     a
2   sh 1927.95 94.42     a
3   tj  532.24 10.77     b
4   cq  613.09  8.58     b
5   nj 1459.86 38.07     c
6   wh 1024.58 94.14     c
7   xm  684.63 30.43     c
8   xa      NA 45.73     c
9   cs  708.35 41.39     c
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `dplyr::case_when` and `stringr::str_detect` you could do this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(level = case_when(str_detect(city, "bj|sh" ) ~ "a",
                           str_detect(city, "cq|tj" ) ~ "b",
                           TRUE ~ "c"))
#>   city    area price level
#> 1   bj 1580.86  9.51     a
#> 2   sh 1927.95 94.42     a
#> 3   tj  532.24 10.77     b
#> 4   cq  613.09  8.58     b
#> 5   nj 1459.86 38.07     c
#> 6   wh 1024.58 94.14     c
#> 7   xm  684.63 30.43     c
#> 8   xa      NA 45.73     c
#> 9   cs  708.35 41.39     c
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>